# Some PHP errors/notices not displaying call stack information within Slim Framework

Tags: error-handling, php, slim

I'm using the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

Most PHP errors in my application output normal PHP error messages

**Example code with an error that outputs the Call Stack:**

```
echo 'missing semicolon at eol'
```

**Error Output:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in /data/www/app/routes/companies_routes.php on line 737
Call Stack:
    0.0002     637144   1. {main}() /data/www/html/index.php:0
```

But other errors ( maybe just notices ) output a limited message that doesn't have a line number, file name, or call stack.  This makes debugging these errors extremely time consuming.

**Code with an error that outputs a limited error message**

```
echo $an_undefined_variable;
```

**Limited Message**

```
Undefined variable: an_undefined_variable
```

I can't figure out what's going on.  I've never had this problem before.  I suspect it has something to do with the way Slim handles PHP errors.  I've tried wrapping these errors in Try/Catch blocks, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Slim is handling exceptions itself ( some sort of default behavior I've yet to track down ).

I've got my code wrapped in Try/Catch blocks, so when Slim catches a PHP error, it's throwing it's own Exception that I'm then outputting in my Catch block.  If I remove my Catch block, Slim them outputs it's own complete error message that contains the stack as usual.

This surely means I'm not using Slim quite right, but that's a different question.